# Switching between menus also closes the menu

Tags: bug, mobile-web, top-bar

When opening a menu, e.g. inbox, and then switching to another one, e.g. site list, the menu will be visible for a short time and then it is closed.

Browser:

- IE 11 on WP 8.1
- Edge on WP 10

Comment: Just reproduced this on the same browser (well, WP8.1).

Comment: Once I have a menu on the left side of the topbar open, moving the mouse pointer to another menu seemlessly shows the new menu, so all looks OK on Firefox 37 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.